# How to turn off oldstyle numbers

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

There are lots of sets of instructions for using oldstyle numbers (e.g. [Utilizing oldstyle figures without resorting to \oldstylenums](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/utilizing-oldstyle-figures-without-resorting-to-oldstylenums)) but what might I do to turn them off completely?

The detailed story is that I'm using the Kurier font and `hyperref` with the `frenchlinks` option, so that citations are rendered in small caps, which the font thinks of as oldstylenums.  So far I even managed to use the `cite` package to substitute a typewriter font:

```
\renewcommand\@citess[1]{{\ttfamily [#1]}}
```

but

```
\renewcommand\@citess[1]{{\rmfamily [#1]}}
```

just supplies the same oldstylenums I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If the old style numbers are located in the small caps version of this font and you want to have small caps font for these texts there is IMHO not much what you can do. Basically you then need the numbers be typeset in another font (face) than the letters, which isn't really simple to do.

Comment: @Martin: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try to change the font for the citations, eg

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{latex6.bib}
@book{voss,
author={Herbert Vo{\ss}},
title={A Book},
publisher={lehmanns media},
year=2011,
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kurier,cite}
\usepackage[frenchlinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cite[1]{{\fontfamily{fxb}\selectfont[#1]}}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
foo~\cite{voss}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{latex6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Linux Libertine is quite different from Kurier.

Comment: @greg: did I said anything different?

Answer (score 5):

If the old style numbers are located in the small caps version of this font and you want to have small caps font for these texts there is IMHO not much what you can do. Basically you then need the numbers be typeset in another font (face) than the letters, which isn't really simple to do.