# Which quote for truncated year number?

Tags: typography

Which is the correct single quote to use to show a truncated year number? In the example below is it (first), (second) or (third)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

First: from '98 to '07 

Second: from `98 to `07 

Third: from \textquotesingle 98 to \textquotesingle 07

\end{document}
```

In the typographic rules, at least for Italian, it is not clear. I prefer (third) but it is not very "typographic", someone said.

Comment: What's the name of the effect or font of numbers that go outside, underneath, the text-line?

Comment: Subscript? BTW, which is the relationship with the question?

Comment: I actually looked up _truncated numbers_ that go below the line. The answer? In Graphic Design SE: [georgia](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/looking-for-a-font-similar-to-georgia-but-without-the-numbers-dipping-as-they-d). The word "truncated" awakened this interest of mine. That's all. People writing numbers might find (it's just my hunch) this typography interesting.

Comment: Ah! Now understand. They are called old style figures. Check: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41095/which-latex-fonts-have-old-style-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's an omission, the normal apostrophe `'` should be used.

```
First: from '98 to '07
```

However, some style manuals (such as the Oxford Style Manual) advocates not truncating a year in numerical form.

Answer (score 5):

As per [Butterick's Practical Typography](http://practicaltypography.com/apostrophes.html), it is called apostrophe and it should be curly, like a single closing quote.