# Package tgpagella and text figures

Tags: fonts, pdftex, oldstylenums

Is there a way that text figures (old style numerals) can be set as default for text when loading the package `tgpagella`? I get them if I use the .otf files under `XeLaTeX`, but I'd like to get them when running `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: I'm afraid this feature is not supported.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/utilizing-oldstyle-figures-without-resorting-to-oldstylenums

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Old style numbers in TeX Gyre Pagella

The TeX Gyre fonts contain four sets of numbers. The names prefixed with `/` are the PostScript glyph names:

- `/zero`, `/one`, `/two`, …
  The "normal" digits with equal widths, suitable for tabulars.
- `/zero.prop`, `/one.prop`, `/two.prop`, …
  The "normal" digits with proportinal widths.
- `/zero.taboldstyle`, `/one.taboldstyle`, `/two.taboldstyle`, …
  Old style digits with equal widths, suitable for tabulars.
- `/zero.oldstyle`, `/one.oldstyle`, `/two.oldstyle`, …
  Old style digits with proportional widths.

### The manual way

In the font setup for LaTeX only the digits with equal widths are available.
The "default" are the "normal" digits with equal widths except for small caps.
Manually you get old style numbers via package `textcomp` and `\oldstylenums` or
via small caps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

0123456789\textdollar\textcent

\oldstylenums{0123456789}\textdollaroldstyle\textcentoldstyle

\textsc{0123456789\textdollar}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

### Patching the encoding

In the font map file `qpl-ec.map`, `qpl.map` or `pdftex.map` the font `ec-qplr` is used
in the example above. The map line is:

```
TeXGyrePagella-Regular "encqec ReEncodeFont" <q-ec.enc <qplr.pfb
```

The encoding file `q-ec.enc` defines which glyphs are used for the slots of the
font encoding:

```
% [some coment lines]
/encqenc [
/grave
/acute
...
/zero
/one
...
/nine
...
] def
```

There we could replace the glyph names for the digits. Let us copy the file to
`q-ec-taboldstyle.enc`. There the digits are replaced by the variant with
suffix `.taboldstyle`.

Now pdfTeX allows to replace the map line using `\pdfmapline` that should be used
before the font is used. For example, this can be done right at the beginning
of the TeX document:

```
\pdfmapline{=ec-qplr TeXGyrePagella-Regular "encqec ReEncodeFont" <q-ec-taboldstyle.enc <qplr.pfb}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\begin{document}
0123456789
\end{document}
```

Then the numbes are set using `/<num>.taboldstyle` instead of `/<num>`:

> [image: 0123456789]

This trick does not change the font for LaTeX/TeX. The glyph metrics (`TFM` file) are
not changed. Because we have used `taboldstyle` instead of `oldstyle`, the widths of
the glyphs remain the same. However, some of the old style digits have a depth, that
is not seen by LaTeX or TeX.

### New `TFM` files

If the correct glyph metrics are needed, then we also need new `TFM` files.
In our case we have `ec-qplr.tfm` (the base name is the first entry in the map line above).
This can be converted to a more human readable form using `tftopl`:

```
tftopl ec-qplr.tfm ec-qplr.pl
```

The file `ec-qplr.tfm` needs the correct directory. The program `kpsewhich` can be used to look for the file. In Linux the can be combined to:

```
tftopl `kpsewhich ec-qplr.tfm` ec-qplr.pl
```

The character metrics for `0`, `1`, and `7` in `ec-qplr.pl`:

```
(CHARACTER C 0
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.6775)
   )
(CHARACTER C 1
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.6775)
   )
...
(CHARACTER C 7
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.6775)
   (CHARIC R 0.025)
   )
```

`CHARWD`, `CHARHT`, `CHARDP`, and `CHARIC` specify the height, width, depth, and italic correction of the character.

Now these values need to be replaced by the values for our `taboldstyle` digits.
Happily they are available in the `TS1` encoding or file `ts1-qplr.tfm`. Alternatively
the small caps font `ec-qplr-sc.tfm` can be used. Again we convert the `.tfm` file
to the readable `.pl` format using `tftopl`. The result for `0`, `1`, `7`:

```
(CHARACTER C 0
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.464)
   (CHARDP R 0.0164995)
   (CHARIC R 0.003)
   )
(CHARACTER C 1
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.4904995)
   (CHARDP R 0.0075)
   )
...
(CHARACTER C 7
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.464)
   (CHARDP R 0.237999)
   (CHARIC R 0.025)
   )
```

This way we create a file `ec-qplr-taboldstyle.pl` with the changed metrics data for
the old style digits. The `.tfm` file is generated by `pltotf`:

```
pltotf ec-qplr-taboldstyle.pl
```

Result: `ec-qplr-taboldstyle.tfm`.

Remark: TFM files are not available for the non-proportinal digits. Thus the metrics need
to be guessed somehow. The `AFM` files contain the glyph bounding boxes that include
side bearings and similar things that are not taken into account for the TeX metric data.
But at least they can give a hint.

Now this font is added and does not replace the old entry for `ec-qplr`:

```
\pdfmapline{+ec-qplr-taboldstyle TeXGyrePagella-Regular "encqec ReEncodeFont" <q-ec-taboldstyle.enc <qplr.pfb}
```

In the next step we need a new font definition file for LaTeX and a new name for the
font in LaTeX. Let us use `qplrtosn`. Then we copy the old `.fd` file to the new one,
e.g. Linux:

```
 cp `kpsewhich t1qplr.fd` t1qplrtosn.fd
```

The new file needs some changes:

- file name in `\ProvidesFile`,
- font name in description text of `\ProvidesFile`,
- date in `\ProvidesFile`,
- font family name `qplr` is replaced by `qplrtosn` (second argument of `\DeclareFont...`),
- `TFM` name `ec-qplr` is replaced by `ec-qplr-taboldstyle`,
- then internal macro prefix `\qpl@` by `\qpltosn@` if we want to use both font families in the same document,

It makes sense to make new `TFM` files for the other fonts, too.

At last we need a new package file `tgpagella-tosn.sty` with changes from `tgpagella.sty`:

- `\ProvidesPackage`,
- internal prefix,
- font family name,

Comment: I'm a bit overwhelmed by your answer. Thanks so much for that. I already have some problems at the patching stage, though. I have followed all the steps but when I try pdfLaTeXing your MWE I get the message `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file q-ec-taboldstyle.enc): cannot open encoding file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!` I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows XP, and I have refreshed the FNDB, updated formats, and run `initexmf -u` as well as `updmap`. Any idea about what can be wrong?

Comment: Where have you put the file?

Comment: In the same folder as the original `.enc` file, namely, in the path of the main TEXMF root going as `MikTeX 2.9\fonts\enc\dvips\tex-gyre`.

Comment: For testing it is sufficient to put the file into the working directory.
For serious installation the distribution tree is not the best place.
MiKTeX makes it easy to add further "root" (texmf/TDS) trees. 
The important thing is to keep the directory layout, e.g.
`<texmf-root-dir>/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre-oldstyle/q-ec-taboldstyle.enc`.

Comment: Alright. Now everything fits. In your answer, you typed: `Let us copy the file to ec-qplr-taboldstyle.enc`, so I named the file like you said, while it ought to be as in the `\pdfmapline` command. Shouldn't that line be edited accordingly?

Comment: And all this because one doesn't want to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX...

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want an easy method to get a version of Palatino with text figures and real small caps with pdfTeX, you can use `\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}` (as in the tufte-latex and classicthesis classes), but this is technically [URW Palladio](http://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/urwpalladio/) rather than TeX Gyre Pagella.