# Missing Fonts on OSX

Tags: fonts, small-caps, oldstylenums

I appear to have absolutely nothing but this ugly default font and a few common styles from the Palatino family.

I'm a newbie at LaTeX, so I hope you can bear with me. But I'm running Mac OS 10.7.5 with TeX Live. I'm using XSLT to compose my `.tex` file, and I can access Palatino by inserting `\usepackage{palatino}`.

The listing [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/palatino/) suggests that Palatino is supposed to have its own styles for both small caps and old style numbering - and that LaTeX should support dozens more font families - but for the life of me I can't obtain any of these in my output PDF.

It would seem that I need to install a whole bunch of fonts, but now I'm just groping in the dark. Please help!

### Example 1: Missing Small Caps in Palatino

My small-caps are simulated by scaling the full-caps glyphs; they're apparently not the separate font style listed for Palatino. This produces unbalanced text weight. (See http://theworldsgreatestbook.com/book-design-part-5/.)

This becomes obvious if I alternate between small-cap letter and explicitly scaled full-cap letter. They are 100% identical:

[image: Small-cap letters are NOT supposed to be identical to scaled-down full-cap characters!]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\def\switchcaps{\fontsize{8pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\textsc{a}{\switchcaps{A}}\textsc{b}{\switchcaps{B}}\textsc{c}{\switchcaps{C}}\textsc{n}{\switchcaps{N}}\textsc{u}{\switchcaps{U}}
\end{document}
```

Log file: http://pastebin.com/43YHxqkg

### Example 2: Missing Oldstyle Numbers in Palatino

When I use `\oldstylenums`, I get the proper style but in a default font, not in Palatino. I found this as a way to access Palatino's oldstyle numbering directly: [[Utilizing oldstyle figures without resorting to \oldstylenums](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/utilizing-oldstyle-figures-without-resorting-to-oldstylenums)], but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{palatino}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{pplj}
Testing \textsc{Testing} 0123456789
\end{document}
```

Log file: http://pastebin.com/8ebHB1EE

### Example 3: Missing Font Families (e.g. Day Roman)

Any other font I try is missing altogether. If it compiles at all it resorts to the default font. Here is an example following the "Usage" directions here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/dayrom/

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{dayrom}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Testing \textsc{Testing} \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

Log file: http://pastebin.com/vj7hgdmf

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It would also be handy to edit in the `.log` file you get for the MWE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've done this before posting the question. As I did, it began to look more and more like a large "fix all my problems!" kind of question, combining three in one. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally satisfied my need by **giving up on the default font system altogether** and **finding a way around it**. It's a compromise, so if someone comes later who can actually fix my installation (or educate me on what I was doing wrong?) I'm willing to pick their answer instead.

It all started with **settling for a font** which I could **obtain in a TTF or OTF file** with the requisite variations (small caps, oldstyle & lining figures) **definitely built in**. So far I found [this](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/sorts-mill-goudy), by the [League of Moveable Type](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/).

Yes, just one solitary option so far. It's a sacrifice of variety for quality. I'm doing it.

A quick search revealed `xelatex` as an alternative to `pdflatex` in my TexLive installation, which can follow a path to the file. **Hook it up, and viola:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{font.otf}
\newfontfamily{\oldstylenums}{font.otf}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\def\switchcaps{\fontsize{6.4pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\textsc{a}{\switchcaps{A}}\textsc{b}{\switchcaps{B}}\textsc{c}{\switchcaps{C}}\textsc{n}{\switchcaps{N}}\textsc{u}{\switchcaps{U}}

Testing \textsc{Testing} 0123456789 \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Problem 1

Use `mathpazo` rather than `palatino`, with the `sc` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\def\switchcaps{\fontsize{8pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\textsc{a}{\switchcaps{A}}%
\textsc{b}{\switchcaps{B}}%
\textsc{c}{\switchcaps{C}}%
\textsc{n}{\switchcaps{N}}%
\textsc{u}{\switchcaps{U}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Problem 2

Use `mathpazo` rather than `palatino`, with the option `osf` (that implies `sc`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{pplj}
Testing \textsc{Testing} 0123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Problem 3

The `dayroman` font is not available in TeX Live (hence MacTeX) for licensing reasons. You must install it with the [`getnonfreefonts-sys`](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) utility.

Note that the font lacks small caps old style figures are the default.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{dayrom}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Testing \textsc{Testing} 0123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

The log file will have a warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/dayrom/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/dayrom/m/n' instead on input line 5.
```

Comment: **Problem 1:** [Error log](http://pastebin.com/aRJm3dPC), [`missfont.log`](http://pastebin.com/mPmZZmTA). **Problem 2:** [Error log](http://pastebin.com/1zqTLYQ1), [`missfont.log`](http://pastebin.com/TKyDY9y5).

Comment: For problem 3, I didn't get past installing the Day Roman font... I followed the instructions you linked to, and `getnonfreefonts` gave me an error. [Here](http://pastebin.com/D9VrDbef) is the log.

Am I doing something wrong? :(

Comment: @Quartz You should be using `getnonfreefonts-sys`.

Comment: Same error. [Log](http://pastebin.com/4ruwPSBx)